# Sound Play on viewpager

Tags: android, audio, android-viewpager

I have made this app. Here used viewpager to image swipe & playing sound which matches the image. Now it is working fine but only problem is on first page image it not playing sound because page is not swipe on start up. How do i solve this problem?.. This is my code

```
public class Learning_Numbers extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    MediaPlayer BG;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(player);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        BG = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
        BG.setLooping(true);
        BG.setVolume(100, 100);
        BG.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        BG.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        BG.start();
    }

    private int[] mAudio = new int[]{R.raw.one,R.raw.two,R.raw.three,R.raw.four,R.raw.five,R.raw.six,R.raw.seven,R.raw.eight,R.raw.nine,R.raw.ten};

    private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.no1,R.drawable.no2,R.drawable.no3,R.drawable.no4,R.drawable.no5,R.drawable.no6,R.drawable.no7,R.drawable.no8,R.drawable.no9,R.drawable.no10};

 OnPageChangeListener player = new OnPageChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0)
        {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Learning_Numbers.this, mAudio[arg0]);
            mp.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
        {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here mp used for image swipe sound & BG for background sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried onCreate this & it works for me..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(player);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        BG = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
        BG.setLooping(true);
        BG.setVolume(100, 100);
        BG.start();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Numbers.this, mAudio[0]);
        mp.start();
    }
```

added last two lines of code again onSelect.. Now it is working fine for me..

Answer (score 0):

have a look into viewpager's source code.

```
void setCurrentItemInternal(int item, boolean smoothScroll, boolean always, int velocity)     {
...
if (mFirstLayout) {
    // We don't have any idea how big we are yet and shouldn't have any pages either.
    // Just set things up and let the pending layout handle things.
    mCurItem = item;
    if (dispatchSelected && mOnPageChangeListener != null) {
         mOnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(item);
    }
    if (dispatchSelected && mInternalPageChangeListener != null) {
        mInternalPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(item);
    }
    requestLayout();
...

// in setAdapter(), It will call setCurrentItemInternal() ..
```

so, simply setOnPageChangeListener(player); before setAdapter. It may work as expected. Handy tricks

Comment: it's not worked... i done this..  myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(player);
  myPager.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: @SuRajPrince  It's a 'bug'(or feature) of viewpage. see  code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27526 . call onpageChangedListener.onPageSelected(0) programmatically.

Comment: Thankyou for your response i have done it.. Can you also tell me if i have multiple imageviewer on screen at time but only one shows at a time on screen & it can be change with the buttons. Is it possible??